# Merging multiple PNG images in a specific order with PHP

Tags: php, image, merge, png

I found this code on SOF that merges PNG images together with transparencies:

```
$imgl = "thumb/pattern.png";
$img2 = "thumb/frame.png";

$dest = imagecreatefrompng($imgl);
$src = imagecreatefrompng($img2);
imagecolortransparent($src, imagecolorat($src, 0, 0));

$src_x = imagesx($src);
$src_y = imagesy($src);
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, 100);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

However, I have multiple images that I want to merge and I want to merge those images in a specific order. How can I alter this code to do just that?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you get the general idea. Watch out for memory limits and execution time limits

```
$imgl = "thumb/pattern.png";
$img = imagecreatefrompng($imgl);

$aImg = array('img2.png','img3.png');

foreach($aImg as $sImg){
 $src = imagecreatefrompng($sImg);
 imagecolortransparent($src, imagecolorat($src, 0, 0));
 $src_x = imagesx($src);
 $src_y = imagesy($src);
 imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, 100);
}
```